# Passing email to path in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls, django-registration

I have code like this:-

`path(something/regex_email/, views.func, name="something"),`

and if user enters any email in url like something `/anyemail/` then the user should be redirected to some page...

But it's not redirecting me to that page and I have seen some previous suggestions regarding to these kinds of questions but those are not working.

## views.py

```
def users(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_email = request.POST.get('').rsplit('/',1)
    print(user_email)
    email = UserApprovedModel.objects.get(email__exact=user_email)
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    form.email = email
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        obj.org = request.user.profile.org
        obj.save()
        return redirect('login')
        # username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        # messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
        # return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
user_org = request.user.profile.org
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(org = user_org)
context = {'form': form, 'user_org': user_org.name, 'profiles': profiles}
return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? This can be an issue with your regular expression or in the view. Please add the actual path and view code if you can.

Comment: re_path('users/(\w+|[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+)/$/',  user_views.users, name='org-users'),

Comment: path('users/r"(^\S+@\S+)$"/',  user_views.users, name='org-users'),

Comment: I have tried both...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got my answer I wanted that in the end of the path if a user give a valid email id which is not in my database, so I want to redirect that user on that page which I want to, so I got that solution with using re_path() function which allows you to give regex path, so this how I used it:

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from users.views import usersAcc

urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^users/\w+|[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/', usersAcc, name='org-users'),
]
```

('something//', views.yourView, name='something')

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try adding the path to be:

```
path('something/<email>/', views.yourView, name='something')
```

Then your view can take that email as a parameter:

```
def yourView(request, email):
```

And then you can handle that return how you see fit. It's hard to give a better answer with little information about what you're trying to accomplish. Hope this helps.

Comment: Its just a registration page in views, I can't show that but that's working fine, I just want to know that how can I redirect the user with url like something/anyemail/.....               another thing you're saying to use '/<email>/'  but this only works when you have already stored something to model's email field..........

Comment: @NikhilBhardwaj what?

Comment: Broo <email> is like an email variable how I can use that......    <email> represents a variable stored in database

Comment: Okk check this :---          I want to redirect a person on a registration page by this url  'registration/some_email/'   and through that url that person should be redirected to the registration page.............

Comment: @NikhilBhardwaj okay so with that variable you can get the email for the registration, use a form to get all other information then save the new user

Comment: My plan is to get the user email id through the url in registration form, but it is not letting me do this

Comment: I just want email @ScottGlascott